# How can I list horizontal data vertically without using transpose?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Excel picture here explains this best.]

I'm given an exported spreadsheet that has data in a single cell, separated by "ALT + ENTER". I want this data to be on each line vertically instead of in a single cell.

I tried to delimit these by "CTRL + J" into columns. I thought maybe this would be easier to list out vertically (row by row). You can see where I'm trying to get at

[image: here]

I tried some VBA that I found online, but I don't know much of anything about it. If I were trying to figure out a VBA solution to this, it would take me even longer because I don't know a lot.

I tried this:
    `Sub vertsplit()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xOutArr As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("please select output cell:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xStr = "" Then
            xStr = xCell.Value
        Else
            xStr = xStr & "," & xCell.Value
        End If
    Next
    xOutArr = VBA.Split(xStr, ",")
    xOutRg.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(xOutArr) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xOutArr)
End Sub`

I replaced the "ALT + ENTERS" with commas and then tried the code above, but it doesn't work well for multiple cells.

[FUNCTION SOLUTION ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9SLp.jpg)

Comment: You'll probably need VBA for this - what have you tried so far? You can likely just split the cells, save to an array, then output to a new range.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Standard 2019 64-bit @ScottCraner

Comment: @BruceWayne I just edited my main post that shows the code I have tried. I can split them into columns. How would I save it to an array in VBA and output them in a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel, one can use TEXTJOIN to create one line of text and parse that:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,$A$1:$A$4),CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the function, but it resolved my issue somewhat. How do I increase the range from $A$1:$A$4 to a higher number?

Comment: Just change the `4`  it to the row you want to end on. ultimately if you want to put the output in a different column then you could just use `A:A`.

Comment: Thanks for this, by the way. It's very useful. When I change the range to anything more than $A:$10, all I get is a value error. I'll post another image in the main post showing what the issue is.

Comment: @hanbanan something is not right.  in your photo the `ROW(1:1)` should be `ROW(6:6)` By the time it got dragged down there.  Try deleting all the outputs and put the formula new in the first cell and drag it down.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2010+ you can use `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform`

- Select a cell in the column
- Get the data from the table/range
- Split by the #lf into rows

[image]

[image]